# How to detect height of text box based on incoming text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The TextInput for `this.state.UserDescription` can vary from 1 line to 4-5 depending on how much a user describes themselves. This is fixed as it is loaded, the user cannot edit this TextInput.  However, the userDescGrid box stays a fixed height no matter what the description, so if the user enters 1 line, theres a lot of empty space below it.

How can i detect, based on the number of lines that will be presented, the right height of box to present (or have it automatically adjust the box `height` value or `flex` value)?

Remember that this will change and needs to be adaptable to different phone devices too.

```
<View style={styles.userDescGrid}>
                  <TextInput style={{color: 'green', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                     value={this.state.UserName}
                     editable = {false}
                     multiline = {false}            
                  />
                  <TextInput style={{color: 'green', fontSize: 13,}}
                     value={this.state.UserDescription}
                     editable = {false}
                     multiline = {true}
                     maxHeight = {80}  
                  />
                  <TextInput style={{color: 'green', fontSize: 13,}}
                     value={this.state.Weblink}
                     editable = {false}
                     maxHeight = {20}    
                  />
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 userDescGrid: {
    flex: 3,
    paddingTop: 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    paddingLeft: 10,
    
  },
})
```

Comment: For multiline textbox, the normal practice is to say fix the height to 3 lines , and then that will be fine because if the user enters more than 3 lines the system will show a scrollbar. If the user enters less than 3 lines, then yes there will be white space left, but it is fine because once the user submits the data, your APP should use TEXT instead of TEXTINPUT to display the submitted data on screen which will not be showing the extra lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this instance you may want to consider using a monospaced font. If you do that then you can determine the number of characters (this.state.UserDescription.length) for a line of text. The height may look something like...

```
height: Math.ceil(this.state.UserDescription.length / numberOfCharactersAMonospaceFontUsesInOneLine) + "unit of measurement";
```